# Azure components needed

Tags: azure

Azure - this is a really dumb Azure question, sorry to all of you who know this stuff backwards.  We're looking at Azure. We want a website, which will contain some relatively static material (white papers, information sheets), and a SQL-Server database which supplies data to website visitors' requests. The database will be about 1GB of actual data which we assume will be about 4 GB of database size. We estimate 14GB of data output per calendar month, worldwide so "zone 2". We need SSL. We have our own software writers to handle loading and outputting data from the database. We do not currently have a SQL-Server licence for this.  Can anyone (some great, patient person) tell us exactly what components from the long list of Azure options and components we need to accomplish this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Without going into much details, here're the components from Windows Azure arsenal you could use in your project:

**Websites** - Windows Azure Websites (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/)

**SQL Server** - Windows Azure SQL Database (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/sql-database/?fb=en-us)

**Static Content** - Though you could store this data with your website also, I would actually recommend using Windows Azure Blob Storage for that (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/storage/).